# Problema DataAnnotations em campos string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

Preciso de uma ajuda para validar um campo `string[]`, pois sempre que envio esse campo vazio, ele retorna erro, mesmo estando no formato correto:

O campo é esse:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail está em um formato inválido.")]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string[] Email { get; set; }
```

Nem sempre esse campo será preenchido, mas sempre que envio ele em branco `null`, ele gera o erro `E-mail está em um formato inválido.`. Será possivel enviar `1` a `n` emails, precisava que cada email que fosse enviado, fosse validado pela expressão regular, saberiam me ajudar ??

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como a ajuda dos amigos acima não funcionou para mim, criei uma pasta `Validation` e dentro dela criei a classe `CustomAnnotations.cs`com o seguinte código.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace EasySistema.Validation
{
    public class CustomAnnotations
    {
     [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
     public class EmailArrayValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            string[] array = value as string[];

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$");

            if (array != null)
            {
                foreach (var email in array)
                {
                    if (email != null)
                    {
                        if (!regex.IsMatch(email))
                        {
                            return new ValidationResult("Email inválido.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }

    }

}
```

E dentro do meu `AddClientViewModels`, utilizo dessa forma:

```
[EmailArrayValidation]
[Display(Name = "E-mail")]
public string[] Email { get; set; }
```

Assim todos os emails dentro do array será validado, e caso exista algum email inválido será retornado o erro.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: você não precisaria dar um override no ValidationResult... não recomendo de forma alguma isso, dê uma olhada no `Validate()` da `IValidatableObject`

Comment: Mas se eu não usar override recebo um erro, `oculta o membro herdado "valor", para que o membro atual substitua essa implementação, adicione a palavra-chave override. Caso contrário adicione a palavra chave-chave new`

Comment: veja a edição da minha resposta com o `Validate()`

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer validar uma coleção de valores eu recomendaria você quebrar e um outro objeto e colocar a validação no elemento, veja o exemplo abaixo

```
[Display(Name = "E-mails")]       
public IEnumerable<EmailViewModel> Emails { get; set; }

public class EmailViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail está em um formato inválido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Agora se você não pode ou não quer mudar a forma de entrada dos dados, você poderia implementar a `IValidatableObject` em sua view model. Veja o exemplo abaixo, mas ainda recomendo a primeira opção por respeitar as recomendações do ASP.Net MVC e não lhe privar de todas as facilidades que o framework lhe proporciona. Fazendo dessa forma você estará abrindo mão das utilidades do scaffolding e dos validadores que já estão disponíveis para você.

```
public class CadastroViewModel : IValidatableObject
{

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]        
    public string[] Email { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Email != null)
        {
            foreach (string entrada in Email)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$");

                if (entrada != null && !regex.IsMatch(entrada))
                    yield return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} não é um e-mail válido.", entrada, new[] { nameof(Email) }));

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu regex pra aceitar vazios:

```
^$|^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```